# Laravel eloquent add to JSON

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

To begin with, sorry for my bad English. I have column:

```
$table->json('images')->nullable();
```

Table is called **albums**. In **images** I would like to store an array with image names, but how can I every time add to that json? My code right now:

```
$album = Album::where('hash', $request->album_hash)->firstOrFail();
$album->update([
    'images' => $request->image->name <= tried to do something.. My uploader everytime calls this function, so I need to get current IMAGES column value, and add new. Like ['first image name', 'second image name'], after update this must be ['first image name', 'second image name', 'third image name'] not just ['third image name']
]);
$album->save();
```

I need to do like laravel increment function, but which works only with int looks like. How can I do that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think its not possible to directly change the JSON as your images data would return as a String.

First get the JSON as a string, then update the Object and update the JSON.

So something like:

```
$album = Album::where('hash', $request->album_hash)->firstOrFail();
$images = json_decode($album->images);

array_push($images,  $request->image->name);

$album->update(['images' => $images]);
$album->save();
```

Note: I didn't check this code, but this should give you an idea of how to handle this

Good luck

Answer (score 5):

```
  $album = Album::where('hash', $request->album_hash)->firstOrFail();
  $arra = json_decode($album->images);
  $arra[] = $request->image->name;
  $album->update([
      'images' => $arra
  ]);
  $album->save();
```

I hope help you